# Mongodb c# adapter 2.2 query - Top 10 sorted result with filter condition and limited columns

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Below is the BSON data format in mongodb. There are 300000 documents in the collection.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "90D6F6B3-B4ED-4665-B3E2-09733F340367", 
    "RootID" : "B607F413-E248-430A-910A-304711BA4BD9", 
    "SubRootId" : "C67F493E-82CB-474B-A3B8-B8769E0878E9", 
    "SubRootVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
    "Orders" : [
        NumberInt(247), 
        NumberInt(205), 
        NumberInt(279), 
        NumberInt(272), 
        NumberInt(256), 
        NumberInt(236), 
        NumberInt(222), 
        NumberInt(250), 
        NumberInt(287), 
        NumberInt(261), 
        NumberInt(281)
    ], 
    "SubRootUpdatedDate" : ISODate("2016-06-20T17:15:14.595+0000"), 
    "UniqueNumber" : NumberLong(15410)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "09ECF9DE-B26F-49FD-B6BD-61B3A2FF4EF4", 
    "RootID" : "B607F413-E248-430A-910A-304711BA4BD9", 
    "SubRootId" : "C67F493E-82CB-474B-A3B8-B8769E0878E9", 
    "SubRootVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
    "Orders" : [
        NumberInt(247), 
        NumberInt(205), 
        NumberInt(279), 
        NumberInt(272), 
        NumberInt(256), 
        NumberInt(236), 
        NumberInt(222), 
        NumberInt(250), 
        NumberInt(287), 
        NumberInt(261), 
        NumberInt(281)
    ], 
    "SubRootUpdatedDate" : ISODate("2016-06-20T17:15:14.609+0000"), 
    "UniqueNumber" : NumberLong(15411)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "038DEB63-196D-4168-9BA8-FA011E14CD09", 
    "RootID" : "919C747A-A024-4615-AFD3-67F86BBD5360", 
    "SubRootId" : "DAEB7FE6-C4BC-4E75-B9AE-AFC1B9999F13", 
    "SubRootVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
    "Orders" : [
        NumberInt(211), 
        NumberInt(203), 
        NumberInt(231), 
        NumberInt(260), 
        NumberInt(213), 
        NumberInt(203), 
        NumberInt(200), 
        NumberInt(213), 
        NumberInt(200), 
        NumberInt(233), 
        NumberInt(220), 
        NumberInt(230), 
        NumberInt(297), 
        NumberInt(256)
    ], 
    "SubRootUpdatedDate" : ISODate("2016-06-20T17:15:09.312+0000"), 
    "UniqueNumber" : NumberLong(15116)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "BFCAC497-7206-4EBD-B2E9-F521A90536A5", 
    "RootID" : "919C747A-A024-4615-AFD3-67F86BBD5360", 
    "SubRootId" : "DAEB7FE6-C4BC-4E75-B9AE-AFC1B9999F13", 
    "SubRootVersion" : NumberInt(2), 
    "Orders" : [
        NumberInt(211), 
        NumberInt(203), 
        NumberInt(231), 
        NumberInt(260), 
        NumberInt(213), 
        NumberInt(203), 
        NumberInt(200), 
        NumberInt(213), 
        NumberInt(200), 
        NumberInt(233), 
        NumberInt(220), 
        NumberInt(230), 
        NumberInt(297), 
        NumberInt(256)
    ], 
    "SubRootUpdatedDate" : ISODate("2016-06-20T17:15:09.347+0000"), 
    "UniqueNumber" : NumberLong(15117)
}
```

Only the sequencenumber and filingid are unique.

I am using the latest c# 2.2 driver to query with the below conditions.

1) top 10 latest RootId records (latest based on SubRootUpdatedDate )
2) records matching the orders list 
3) between a SubRootUpdatedDate date range

This is what I tried

```
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<SubRoot>("SubRoots");

    var sort = Builders<SubRoot>.Sort.Descending(x => x.UniqueNumber);
    var sortByDate = Builders<SubRoot>.Sort.Descending(x => x.SubRootUpdatedDate);
    var filter = Builders<SubRoot>.Filter.In("Orders", new list<int> { 255, 256 , 299, 281});
    filter &= Builders<SubRoot>.Filter.Gt(y => y.SubRootUpdatedDate, minDate);
    filter &= Builders<SubRoot>.Filter.Lt(y => y.SubRootUpdatedDate, maxDate);

    var projection = Builders<SubRoot>.Projection
        .Exclude(x => x.SubRootUpdatedDate)
        .Exclude(x => x.SubRootId)
        .Exclude(x => x.UniqueNumber) 
        .Exclude(x => x._id)
        .Exclude(x => x.Orders)
        .Exclude(x => x.SubRootVersion);

    return collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Sort(sortByDate).Project(projection).ToList();
```

I am unable to do a distinct after using filter and sort. Also I am not able to limit the result to 10 before doing a Tolist(). I want all the filtering, sorting and limiting the data to be done in mongodb. I would want to bring back only the 10 id's matching the search criteria. I have spent enough time on it and I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer myself.

```
    var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
        .Match(Builders<Filing>.Filter.In("Orders", ordersList))
        .Match(x => x.UniqueNumber>= UniqueNumberList)
        .Match(Builders<Filing>.Filter.Gt(y => y.SubRootUpdatedDate, minDate))
        .Match(Builders<Filing>.Filter.Lt(y => y.SubRootUpdatedDate, maxDate))
        .Sort(Builders<Filing>.Sort.Descending(x => x.UniqueNumber))
        .Sort(Builders<Filing>.Sort.Descending(x => x.SubRootUpdatedDate))
        .Group(z => z.RootID, h => new { h.Key })
        .Limit(limitValue)
        .ToList();
```